# Is there a non-blocking version of MPI_Comm_create_group()?

Tags: mpi

Suppose that we want to create 3 communicators for three processes with ranks 0,1 and 2 and the groups of the communicators are {0,1}, {0,2} and {1,2}.

It seems that (see the example code below) if each process calls `MPI_Comm_create_group()` in the following order, there will be a blockage.

**Process 0**

create a communicator for the group {0,1}

create a communicator for the group {0,2}

**Process 1**

create a communicator for the group {1,2}

create a communicator for the group {0,1}

**Process 2**

create a communicator for the group {0,2}

create a communicator for the group {1,2}

What solutions are there? One solution is obviously changing the order of the calls to `MPI_Comm_create_group()`.

The example code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int worldsize, worldrank;

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldsize);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldrank);

    if (worldsize < 3)
    {
        if (worldrank==0) printf("Please launch at least 3 processes!\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }

    MPI_Group worldgroup, newgroup;
    MPI_Comm newcomm1, newcomm2;

    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldgroup);

    int set01[2] = {0, 1};
    int set02[2] = {0, 2};
    int set12[2] = {1, 2};

    switch (worldrank)
    {
        case 0:
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set01, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 0, &newcomm1);
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set02, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 1, &newcomm2);
            break;
        case 1:
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set12, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 2, &newcomm1);
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set01, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 0, &newcomm2);
            break;
        case 2:
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set02, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 1, &newcomm1);
            MPI_Group_incl(worldgroup, 2, set12, &newgroup);
            MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, newgroup, 2, &newcomm2);
            break;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: better write a [MCVE] than asking if you guess right

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I will write an example, but the result of such example might be dependent on the size of the problem (i.e. the number of processes and communicators) and the implementation of MPI that is being used. I'm going to make many communicators among hundreds of processes and the question I've asked is the most simplified case.

Comment: In your example, switching the declaration order of `case 1` is enough to avoid the deadlock. In the general case (with more processes), if each process takes care to `MPI_Comm_create_group` in a prescribed and compatible orde, it would also be fine (lexicographic order of included processes seems ok).

Comment: Although this would solve the deadlock, but still sequentialize the creation of those groups; maybe you're also willing to speed up (i.e. do it in parallel) these creation when you have 1000+ processes and groups?

Comment: @Demi-Lune, I consulted MPI 3 specification briefly. It seems to me that MPI doesn't provide anything that may be called a "non-blocking" version of `MPI_Comm_create_group()` and it is the developer who has to take care of it herself/himself. Since in my problem the communicators are created only once in the beginning of each run, I'm not worried very much about the speed here, at least at the moment. Of course, we always prefer higher speed.

Comment: it is up to you not to create a deadlock when creating the communicators.

Comment: in this case, it is way easier (and probably faster) to use `MPI_Comm_split()`. and use `color=0` if the rank should be part of the new communicator, and `color=MPI_UNDEFINED` otherwise.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, Apparently in my problem `MPI_Comm_split()` is not usable, at least easily. `MPI_Comm_split()` has to be called by each process the same number of times, whereas in my problem (which is not completely described here) different processes can have different numbers of communicators.